# Using Unison / rsync over SSH to synchronize sites where full file system access is required yet root login is disabled

Tags: ssh, rsync, root, unison

Assume two sites **A** and **B** with file server at either end. The contents of `/storage` should be synchronized between the sites, preserving ownership and permissions. There's no all encompassing group that group-owns all of the files in `/storage`. If running Unison or rsync pid=0 it is trivial to do the synchronization. However SSH is to be used as transport and for obvious reasons SSH root login has been disabled on both ends.

How can I keep A and B synchronized with all permissions preserved in that situation. Two methods I can think of:

- Running a secondary SSH that permits root logins yet may only connect over a VPN between A and B.
- adding a special synchronization user which sshd configuration forcibly executes a

  - SUID wrapper to Unison or rsync (*dangerous to get right*).
  - `sudo` wrapper to Unison or rsync

The answers given to the Question [Remotely use root over ssh for unison](https://serverfault.com/questions/341985/remotely-use-root-over-ssh-for-unison) suggest enabling password-less pubkey root login over SSH – I'm not very keen of that solution.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public key root login over SSH is likely your best bet. You could furthermore restrict this access to a single host:

```
AllowUsers root@192.0.2.123
```

Or even use the `Match` directive to get a unique configuration for a given something (address, user, etc):

```
Match Address 192.0.2.123
    PasswordAuthentication no
    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PermitRootLogin yes
```

Answer (score 1):

How to run remote unison instance as root:

#### Remote side

- don't touch your sshd config, especially don't create any *special synchronization [ssh] user* as you state in your question
- create sudo wrapper `vi sunison`:

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
su --preserve-environment -c `which unison` "$@"
```

*(yes, this is for Termux environment, simplify to your needs)*

#### Client side

- run unison with `-servercmd sunison`
- or add to your unison profile `servercmd = sunison`

#### Notes

- something like `servercmd = sudo unison` would be best, but it didn't work for me